# "Smart" solution for $7^{100}+11^{100} \pmod{13}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following exercise: "Find $7^{100}+11^{100} \pmod{13}$".

My long and boring solution is the following:

1. I've found that $7^k \equiv 7^{k \pmod{12}} \pmod{13}$ by calculating $7^k \pmod{13} = 7 \cdot (7^{k-1} \pmod{13}) \pmod{13}$ from $k=1$ until the remainder starts to repeat itself.
2. The same for $11^k \equiv 11^{k \pmod{12}} \pmod{13}$
3. Using the result from steps 1 and 2, $7^{100}+11^{100} \equiv 7^4+11^4 \equiv 9 + 3 \equiv 12 \pmod{13}$

Both steps 1 and 2 require a lot of calculations and I suspect that I've missed some clever trick to avoid them and to solve the exercise in a "smart" way.

Is there a way to improve my solution?

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: Note that $11\equiv -2\pmod {13}$, so $11^4\equiv (-2)^4=2^4\pmod {13}$. That simplifies one step in the calculation.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano, I didn't, but I do now. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up the first step a lot by knowing Fermat's little theorem.

It states that if $p$ is a prime then for any $n$ we have:

$$a^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$$

In your problem $13$ is a prime so we can use it:

$7^{12}\equiv1\pmod{13}$ and $11^{12}\equiv\pmod{13}$

Then note that $100\equiv4\pmod{12}$ and you get to your solution.

You still need to work out $7^4\pmod{13}$ and $11^4\pmod{13}$.

Answer (score 2):

Thank to the guys at the comment section, the improved solution is the following:
$$ 7^{100} + 11^{100}$$
$$= 7^{8 \cdot (13-1) + 4} + 11^{8 \cdot (13-1) + 4}$$
$$ \equiv 7^4 + 11^4$$
$$ \equiv (7^2)^2 + (-2)^4 $$
$$\equiv 10^2 + 16$$
$$\equiv 9 + 3 = 12 \pmod{13} $$